# div background smaller than its content with css (without specifying the width in % or px)

Tags: html, css

This is what I have:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; background: red; text-align: center">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Plain-M%26Ms-Pile.jpg/280px-Plain-M%26Ms-Pile.jpg" height="170" width="170" style="border-radius:700px; border: 10px solid white;">
</div>
```

This is what I want:

[image]

I've tried borders, inset shadow, and many other options in CSS but none of them seem to work for my purpose.

Is there any way to make the div's background smaller than the contents WITHOUT having to specify its height?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tLd9T/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tLd9T/8/

Comment: You just need to add negative margins to the image

Answer (score 1):

Adding another div will do it;

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
  <div style="width:100%;height:100px;position:absolute;left:0;top:45px;background:red;z-index:-1;"></div>
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Plain-M%26Ms-Pile.jpg/280px-Plain-M%26Ms-Pile.jpg" height="170" width="170" style="border-radius:700px; border: 10px solid white;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLYQa/))?

```
div {
    margin: 40px 0;
}

img {
    margin: -40px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but you can use background-size and position(if needed).

```
background-size: 50% 50%; /* background half the size of the div */
background-position: 50% 50%; /* to center it */
```