# How can I create a marker strike through effect?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a marker strike through effect, as shown in the image below.

> [image: marker strike through effect]

I've tried wrapping the text in two `span` elements. The inner one with negative top and bottom margins with the intent to reduce the height. The outer `span` sets the background and has positive margins to compensate for for the negative margins of the inner `span`. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823532/div-background-smaller-than-its-content-with-css-without-specifying-the-width-i) question.

My current attempt doesn't function. This might be due to the fact that I'm using inline elements. However I don't want the whole block stroked but only the text inside the block.

```css
.item .mark {
  background-color: #ffd100;
  margin: 13px 0;
}

.item .mark .text {
  margin: -13px 0;
}

/* irrelevant CSS */

.item {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.item h1 {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.item .button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.item .button:hover {
  background-color: #ffd100;
}

.item .button a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="item">
  <h1><span class="mark"><span class="text">Foo</span></span></h1>
  <p>
    Jerky pastrami pork belly tongue bresaola. Flank t-bone tri-tip, leberkas
    ribeye salami shoulder ball tip. Capicola frankfurter salami venison
    turducken pig burgdoggen shankle drumstick tail fatback. Turkey pork ham
    ball tip jowl beef rump boudin.
  </p>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">GO</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this? [https://jsfiddle.net/hmq7g8yc/](https://jsfiddle.net/hmq7g8yc/)

Comment: Isn't there a text-decoration for strikeout in CSS, and even the HTML-native <del> and <s>-tags? I don't know about the visual effects of these, though (I'm blind).

Comment: uhm ... I think the solution in the "already asked question" is not the optimal one for your specific case, now I cannot post the answer since the post is closed ;(

Comment: @TimB Yes there is. It had more styling options than I expected, the following comes pretty close: `text-decoration: line-through #ffd100 0.4em;` but leaves the stroke in front of the text, whereas it should be behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to use a `linear-gradient()` as your background:

```css
.item .mark {
  /* here we use the linear-gradient function: */
  background: linear-gradient(
    /* the direction of the gradient: */
    to bottom,
    /* the starting colour: */
    transparent,
    /* the colour continues, until the colour stop
       at 40%: */
    transparent 40%,
    /* the next colour, starting at the same point,
       so the colour change is abrupt rather than a
       smooth gradient: */
    #ff0 40%,
    /* the colour continues until the next colour-stop: */
    #ff0 60%,
    /* at the next colour stop the colour changes again,
       this time back to transparent: */
    transparent 60%,
    /* and remains transparent until the end of the linear-gradient: */
    transparent);
  margin: 13px 0;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```css
.item .mark {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    transparent,
    transparent 40%,
    #ff0 40%,
    #ff0 60%,
    transparent 60%,
    transparent);
  /* unchanged: */
  margin: 13px 0;
  /* padding set to 0.5em on the left and right sides,
     in order that the 'strike-through' extends beyond
     the side of the text: */
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}


/* most CSS removed for brevity */

.item {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.item h1 {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="item">
  <h1><span class="mark">Foo</span></h1>
  <!-- removed for brevity -->
</div>
```

References:

- [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).
- [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

Comment: This is probably the cleanest solution out of the bunch. Too bad multi position stops isn't yet widely supported. `linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 40%, #ffd100 40% 60%, transparent 60%)` is a lot shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use borders in order to achieve the striking effect.

You can change the width of the striking by changing the width of `border-bottom: 0.25em solid #ffd100;`

```css
.item .mark {
  position: relative;
}
.item .mark::after {
  border-bottom: 0.25em solid #ffd100;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  margin-top: calc(0.125em / 2 * -1);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -1000;
}

/* irrelevant CSS */

.item {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.item h1 {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.item .button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.item .button:hover {
  background-color: #ffd100;
}

.item .button a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="item">
  <h1><span class="mark"><span class="text">Foo</span></span></h1>
  <p>
    Jerky pastrami pork belly tongue bresaola. Flank t-bone tri-tip, leberkas
    ribeye salami shoulder ball tip. Capicola frankfurter salami venison
    turducken pig burgdoggen shankle drumstick tail fatback. Turkey pork ham
    ball tip jowl beef rump boudin.
  </p>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">GO</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty close. The stroke has to be behind the text, not in front of it. But setting the suggested styling on `.item .mark::before` instead and adding `.item .mark { position: relative; }` seems to move the stroke behind the text.

Comment: Instead you can also set the `z-index` of the `::after` pseudo-class accordingly.
I edited my post as to the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> Click on the GO Button, you will see the animated marker strike

```js
$("#go").click(function() {
  $('.item h1').toggleClass('widthh');
});
```

```css
.item .mark {
  background-color: #ffd100;
  margin: 13px 0;
}

.item .mark .text {
  margin: -13px 0;
}

.item {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.item .button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.item .button:hover {
  background-color: #ffd100;
}

.item .button a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* irelevant CSS */



.item h1 {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.item h1:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  left: -10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  background: #ffb300;
  transform: translateY(-35%) rotate(-3deg);
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: .3s all ease;
}

.item h1.widthh:before {
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="item">
  <h1 class="widthh">Foo</h1>
  <p>
    Jerky pastrami pork belly tongue bresaola
  </p>
  <div class="button"><a href="#" id="go">GO</a></div>
</div>
```

> I only add pseudo element

Comment: Could move the relevant CSS above the `/* irrelevant CSS */` line? So it's clear what you've added/changed.

Comment: i only add :before